# Flask-SQLAlchemy "MySQL server has gone away" when using HAproxy

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, haproxy

I've built a small python REST service using Flask, with Flask-SQLAlchemy used for talking to the MySQL DB.

If I connect directly to the MySQL server everything is good, no problems at all.  If I use HAproxy (handles HA/failover, though in this dev environment there is only one DB server) then I constantly get `MySQL server has gone away` errors if the application doesn't talk to the DB frequently enough.

My HAproxy client timeout is set to 50 seconds, so what I think is happening is it cuts the stream, but the application isn't aware and tries to make use of an invalid connection.

Is there a setting I should be using when using services like HAproxy?

Also it doesn't seem to reconnect automatically, but if I issue a request manually I get `Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back`, which is odd since it is just a `select()` call I'm making, so I don't think it is a `commit()` I'm missing - or should I be calling commit() after every ORM based query?

Comment: I went through the same problem of getting 'MySQL server has gone away' and it usually had to do with the size of the result set returned by query. Try executing the same query but enforcing a limit and select fewer columns.

Comment: @AndyC Any luck on this problem? I'm having the same, and setting the pool recycle doesn't fix it!

Comment: @SJoshi setting `SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE = 30` in the app.config (my HAproxy timeout was 50) worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to tidy up this question with an answer I'll post what I (think I) did to solve the issues.

**Problem 1: HAproxy**

- Either increase the HAproxy client timeout value (globally, or in the frontend definition) to a value longer than what MySQL is set to reset on (see this [interesting and related](https://serverfault.com/questions/355750/mysql-lowering-wait-timeout-value-to-lower-number-of-open-connections) SF question)
- Or set `SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE = 30` (30 in my case was less than HAproxy client timeout) in Flask's app.config so that when the DB is initialised it will pull in those settings and recycle connections before HAproxy cuts them itself.  Similar to [this issue on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14424137/1808861).

**Problem 2: `Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back`**

I believe I fixed this by tweaking the way the DB is initialised and imported across various modules.  I basically now have a module that simply has:

```
  from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
  db = SQLAlchemy()
```

Then in my main [application factory](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/appfactories/) I simply:

```
  from common.database import db
  db.init_app(app)
```

Also since I wanted to easily load table structures automatically I initialised the metadata binds within the app context, and I think it was this which cleanly handled the `commit()` issue/error I was getting, as I believe the database sessions are now being correctly terminated after each request.

```
 with app.app_context():
    # Setup DB binding
    db.metadata.bind = db.engine
```

Comment: Thanks for updating with an answer. For anyone else with this problem, one thing that should be checked out too is the my.cnf to see what the wait_timeout is like. I have a vanilla MariaDB and it's apparently set to 10 minutes instead of 8 hours.

Comment: @SJoshi I use mariadb , have the same problem too.thanks for your comment.