# Flask, SQLAlchemy and MySQL Server has gone away

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, mariadb

I have a SQLAlchemy connection to MariaDB (MySQL) server in my Flask application. I use scoped session and I remove session on application context teardown.

```
engine = create_engine(config.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, pool_recycle=3600, isolation_level='READ_COMMITTED')
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=True, bind=engine))

@app.teardown_appcontext
def shutdown_session(exception=None):
    db_session.remove()
```

Also I use uwsgi with 8 workers to bind my application to nginx.

Sometimes I get error "MySQL server has gone away" during the request. When I repeat the request I have no errors, but if I repeat it again, I get error again. After repeating requests several times, the problem disapears.
It happes after application restart (not always) and sometimes after MySQL restart.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6473271/2375305) answer advises close session after each usage, I think that removing session on teardown_appcontext is the same thing.

Also I tried manually [rollback session](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34684717/2375305), but it does not help.

Comment: There can be a variety of reasons for this. I had a very long ordeal that was chronicled here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34684554/does-this-thread-local-flask-sqlachemy-session-cause-a-mysql-server-has-gone-aw/34684717#34684717  .... that specific issue came down to `pool_recycle` needing to be set less than MySQL `timeout` value

Comment: @Busturdust I set `pool_recycle` lesser than MySQL timeout, but it did not help me. It is hard to reproduce this error. Last time I met this error after MySQL server reboot. But when I rebooted it again, error did not appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the real reason of this trouble: shared memory used by 8 uwsgi workers. After adding `lazy-apps = true` into uwsgi config MySQL connection works correct.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution works properly for me. Server connection errors are handled in methods of custom Session and Query (for ORM queries) classes.

```
from sqlalchemy import exc, create_engine, MetaData
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker, Session, Query

MAX_RETRIES = 2

class RetryQuery(Query):
    def _execute_and_instances(self, *args, **kwargs):
        retry = MAX_RETRIES
        while retry:
            retry -= 1
            try:
                return super(RetryQuery, self)._execute_and_instances(*args, **kwargs)
            except exc.SQLAlchemyError as e:
                if e.orig.args[0] in (2006, 2013, 2014, 2045, 2055) and retry and e.connection_invalidated:
                    continue
                else:
                    raise


class RetrySession(Session):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['query_cls'] = RetryQuery
        super(RetrySession, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def execute(self, *args, **kwargs):
        retry = MAX_RETRIES
        while retry:
            retry -= 1
            try:
                return super(ReconnSession, self).execute(*args, **kwargs)
            except exc.SQLAlchemyError as e:
                if e.orig.args[0] in (2006, 2013, 2014, 2045, 2055) and retry and e.connection_invalidated:
                    continue
                else:
                    raise


engine = create_engine(config.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, pool_recycle=3600, isolation_level='READ_COMMITTED')
db_session = scoped_session(class_=RetrySession, sessionmaker(autocommit=True, bind=engine))

db_session.execute("SELECT col FROM table")
db_session.query(User).all()
```